# How to specify stdlib path for ARM cross compiler in clang with cmake?

Tags: c, cmake, linker, arm, clang

I am using cmake with clang to compile a C project for an ARM cortex-m4 MCU (armv7e-m, softfp).

Currently I am using the GCC Toolchain includes and libraries so I specify them as follows in the Toolchain cmake file:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT /opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/arm-none-eabi)
```

This works as expected and there isnt any problem with the includes. As the linker requires the standard libraries I noticed it looks bby default for libm and libc in

`/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/arm-none-eabi/lib`.

However, I would like to use the std libraries from another path, for this case:

`/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/softfp`

I tried using `-L/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/softfp` but I noticed that the other path takes priority.

So my question is how can I tell clang to look for the standard libraries in this path? My current solution is not setting CMAKE_SYSROOT at all, then I add `-nostdinc` to the compiler flags and include the std includes from the GCC toolchain  manually

```
-I${ARM_TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/arm-none-eabi/include
-I${ARM_TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/include
```

That allows me to the tell the linker the paths for the lib I want:

```
-L${ARM_TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/softfp
```

As I am not experience with clang and cmake I am not sure if this is the best way to override a library path or tell clang to look first in another path.

Comment: You could try to set variables [CMAKE_<LANG>_STANDARD_LIBRARIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/variable/CMAKE_LANG_STANDARD_LIBRARIES.html) and [CMAKE_<LANG>_STANDARD_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/variable/CMAKE_LANG_STANDARD_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html), as described in that [bugreport](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18222). Not sure whether this is correct or the best way, but it could just work.

Comment: Just as a side note, I would like to mention https://github.com/dockcross/dockcross, which I like for cross-compiling (it provides docker images coming with toolchains).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from Tsyvarev worked out. I added the following to my toolchain cmake file

```
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES 
    ${ARM_TOOLCHAIN_BIN_DIR}/../arm-none-eabi/include
    )
```

Afterwards I specify the library paths where cmake should look for the libm libc.

```
target_link_directories(${EXECUTABLE} PRIVATE
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/my_custom_libs
    )
```

I did not use  `CMAKE_C_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` as the library names are the same as the standard naming. Just in case you want to add your own std libs with different names you just have to add `-nostdlib` flag and then its up to you to provide all the std defs that your project uses for the specific cpu.